# Move section content to other repeat section

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML that uses a new format that I use for document generation. For compatibility reasons I would like to keep a different format for when generating older documents. As such I would like to move everything inside the ADDRESSES block to each ORDERS/ORDER block.

Simplified example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1"?>
<XML>
    <ADDRESSES>
        <ADDRESSEE>
            ...
        </ADDRESSEE>
        <ORDCMP>
            ...
        </ORDCMP>
        <ORDCUSTOMER>
            ...
        </ORDCUSTOMER>
    </ADDRESSES>
    <ORDERS>
        <ORDER>

        </ORDER>
        <ORDER>
        </ORDER>
        <ORDER>
        </ORDER>
    </ORDERS>
</XML>
```

I have tried with a XSLT to remove the ADDRESSES block which works and then copy each element from the ADDRESSES block into each ORDERS/ORDER block which doesn't work.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Remove the whole ADDRESSES block -->
    <xsl:template match="ADDRESSES">
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- And now start adding individual ADDRESSES items to each order -->
    <xsl:template match="ORDERS/ORDER">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:template match="ADDRESSES/ADDRESSEE">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I would like my XML to be is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1"?>
<XML>
    <ORDERS>
        <ORDER>
            <ADDRESSEE>
                ...
            </ADDRESSEE>
            <ORDCMP>
                ...
            </ORDCMP>
            <ORDCUSTOMER>
                ...
            </ORDCUSTOMER>
        </ORDER>
        <ORDER>
            <ADDRESSEE>
                ...
            </ADDRESSEE>
            <ORDCMP>
                ...
            </ORDCMP>
            <ORDCUSTOMER>
                ...
            </ORDCUSTOMER>
        </ORDER>
        <ORDER>
            <ADDRESSEE>
                ...
            </ADDRESSEE>
            <ORDCMP>
                ...
            </ORDCMP>
            <ORDCUSTOMER>
                ...
            </ORDCUSTOMER>
        </ORDER>
    </ORDERS>
</XML>
```

And of course I would like to keep everything in the XML that is already there, except for the ADDRESSES block.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is it the same (single) ADDRESSEE for all ORDERs? Your XML says ADDRESSES, which suggests there could be several.

Comment: In the new version I moved all those addresses to a main section because the addresses do not change per order. For the old version I still need those addresses to be repeated per order. So yes, everything within the ADDRESSES block is the same for each ORDER

Comment: Also I would like to know if I can move everything within the ADDRESSES block in one go or must I define each separate item (e.g. ORDCUSTOMER, ADDRESSEE, etc.) in the xslt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot define a template in a template. Use `xsl:copy-of` instead. So change your third template to

```
<xsl:template match="ORDERS/ORDER">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="/XML/ADDRESSES/*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This copies all elements under `ADDRESSES` to each `ORDER` element.

Or, if there are several `ADDRESSES` for different groups of orders, you can try a relative path instead

```
<xsl:copy-of select="../../ADDRESSES/*" />
```